# Jerky Silverlight 4 animations when running app in OOB

Tags: performance, animation, silverlight-4.0, mouseevent

I was playing with new Silverlight 4 and to my surprise when I run my sample application in OOB all animations become very jerky when I moved mouse around during animations, but when I run my app in browser animations are smooth even when moving mouse around.

I tried my app on two different computers, turned on GPU acceleration in OOB settings - and got the same jerky result.

Is this a know problem with Silverlight?

I'm running WinXP SP3

**UPDATE:** Tested on 3 Windows 7 machines - no issues at all (running in OOB and in browser), tested additional 5 WinXP SP3 machines - 100% reproducible problem on any Silverlight 4 app running in OOB

Comment: OOB performance on WinXP is pitiful. I think it works better on Windows 7 because there is hardware acceleration for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on "Enable GPU acceleration in Out of Browser" isn't enough. That setting works in tandem with .CacheMode property, which must be set on all elements (or a top-level element) whose rendered bitmap will be sent to the GPU.

From there, the GPU can hardware accelerate rotations, scalings, opacities, clipping. If your animation does any of that, you'll need to set element.CacheMode = "BitmapCache" on the top level element you are animating.

Again, you'll need to turn on the "enable GPU acceleration" for this to work.

**If either step is missing, you won't get GPU accelerated.**

A couple of caveats for hardware acceleration:

- Pixel shaders and perspective transforms are not HW accelerated last I checked.
- HW acceleration works on XP, but requires that you have a video card from NVidia, ATI, or Intel, **and** the driver date must be post Nov 2004. Anything less and nothing will be accelerated.

I recommend reading [MSDN's article on hardware acceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28VS.95%29.aspx).